# Getting Error 500 when trying to use RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to figure out the code to make all my links with no extension to be redirected to a certain page using .htaccess. For example:

```
http://mysite.com/link
```

Gets rewritten to:

```
http://mysite.com/run.php?id=link
```

I have tried the following code but I receive an Internal Error 500 and can't even access my homepage.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /run.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What does the Apache error log tell you about the cause of the HTTP 500 response? Without that information, it's much more difficult to answer your question; if you'll retrieve it from the log and add it to the question, it's a lot likelier you will get a helpful answer.

Comment: I'm new to this how do I go about doing that? I can't seen to find the correct error log file

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help I think found the answer:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^([A-z,0-9,_,-]+)/?$              /run.php?id=$1     [QSA]
```

This seems to work. Although I'm not soo sure if anything else is affected. The homepage still loads if I type www.mysite.com/index.php so I think it is ok.